# Surface covered by buffers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, buffer, qgis-plugins

In QGIS, I have plotted buffers around points. I would like to calculate the area which falls under buffers without over counting due to buffer overlaps.

Is there a quick and easy way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you make a buffer you can choose to dissolve (or not) the buffers.  When you check dissolve, the overlapping buffers will be merged together. So there will be no double count when calculating the area.

[image]

Now you can calculate the area with the fieldcalculator.  See: [How to calculate polygon areas in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23355/how-to-calculate-polygon-areas-in-qgis)