# Analyse spatial data and extract results in tabular form in QGIS

Tags: qgis, analysis

I'm sorry if this question is badly framed, I only started with GIS and QGIS 2 days ago so I don't know any terminology yet - I'll try to explain as best I can.

I have 2 layers in QGIS (1.8, on Win7), one with geological information, and the other with the state boundaries.

I want to get out a report which tells me the composition of each state, i.e. a table of the form:

```
State name    Rock type 1    Rock type 2
State1            32 %           68 %      
State2             5 %           95 %
```

I guess this is a pretty basic thing to want to do, but I'm having trouble finding how on my own because I don't know what to search for.

Sorry if bad question, thanks for any help.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what information is available in each layer. Most likely the solution will involve a clip - creating a sub-table that only has geology information for Arizona, and so on. From there, you can calculate the percentages, and then recombine the sub-tables at the end. So look up help on selection, clipping, and area calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both layers are vector layers (as opposed to raster, which pixelates when zoomed close), I would do an `intersect` between the two, found under `Vector->Geoprocessing Tools`. This creates a new layer that cuts each rock area type out of the state geography and keeps that attribute.

Then you can add an area field per instructions for the field calculator [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23355/how-to-calculate-polygon-areas-in-qgis) and then hop into your spreadsheet tool of choice to crosstab area by rock type by state.

Comment: There is good support for spatial analysis rasters in QGIS, if that is what form the geological information is in.