# How to calculate polygon areas in acres or square miles instead of feet?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, field-calculator

I have a layer in State Plane NAD83. When I use "Vector|Geometry Tools|Add/export geometry columns" or Field Calculator they both create the area in feet. What if I want acres or square miles? Thanks

[How to calculate polygon areas in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23355/how-to-calculate-polygon-areas-in-qgis)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to calculate acres in QGIS, open the field calculator and and use the following code:

`$area / 43560`