# Extracting Derived Z-coordinate data

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, data, attribute-table, geometry

I am trying to extract the z coordinate value from the derived attributes, similar to [How to re-calculate area, perim, p2a,width and length in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63771/how-to-re-calculate-area-perim-p2a-width-and-length-in-qgis) but I cannot see a dedicated operator for finding the z coordinate like when trying to find area within the field calculator.

I have tried extraction of geometry tools > extract nodes & export/add geometry columns
[image: Screen shot of the attributes, I want Closest vertex Z to be a new column]

Comment: Have you tried using the expression `z($geometry)`?

Comment: Yes it only returns Null from the vector layer, after extracting the nodes the Z coordinate is lost and I am only left with X & Y

Comment: I have a similar problem. To get Z coordinate from polygons you need to tell what is the vertice you want Z. **z(point_n($geometry ,1))** The problem while calculating Z coordinate from polygons is that Z returned is an integer.
I need Z real, i´ve tryed a lot of other ways inside calculator and keep getting an integer.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/155500)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try [How to „extract“ z-values ?](http://isticktoit.net/?p=1359) to open the attribute-table, go directly into the field-calculator. Within the geometry-functions you will find z

Just calculate z on the geometry: `z ($geometry)`

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Apparently the `z` function available in the Geometry section of the field calculator works well with points. I was able to find a solution to a similar problem of that asked by the OP by using `z(start_point($geometry))` in the field calculator.