# How to calculate area of a contour in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have prepared a contour map of an area in a shapefile in QGIS. I want to know how can I calculate area of a particular contour?

Comment: Convert polygons and see related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23355/how-to-calculate-polygon-areas-in-qgis?rq=1

Comment: Contours are usually lines. Line does not have area. I suggest edits to your question