# Selecting polygon with the largest area in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, area, qgis-modeler, select-by-attribute

[image]

I would like to select the largest number in a column of an attribute table by "Select by attributes" in QGIS to select the polygon with the largest area. How would be the expression for that? I do not want to sort the column and select the polygon per hand, because I want to use it in the modeler.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 10):

You would be better off using ["Select by expression"](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#select-by-expression) instead of ["Select by attribute"](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#select-by-attribute). Your expression should be something like:

```
"AREA" = maximum("AREA")
```

Replace `"AREA"` in the expression with the name of the column.

Alternatives are:

```
$area = maximum($area)
```

or

```
area($geometry) = maximum(area($geometry))
```

For more details about the difference between `$area` and `area($geometry)`, please refer to this thread: [Calculating polygon areas in shapefile using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23355/calculating-polygon-areas-in-shapefile-using-qgis).

For example, the following screenshot shows how to select the polygon with the maximum value of the `"POP_EST"` field using "Select by expression" from the Processing Toolbox (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

[image]

Comment: Unfortunatly using this expression throws the error: "syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting $end".
I tried replacing maximum with max, but then the whole area is selected.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of the window where you are using the expression and the error is occurring?

Comment: I added the screenhot above.
A   Layer with the polygons;
B   Attribute Table;
C   Select by Expression Window;
D   Expression;
E   Processing Window;
F   Error Message;

Comment: Try using the expression without the quotations `"`.
Something like `AREA = maximum(AREA)`

Comment: Now the error message changed in " Error executing algorithm Select by expression syntax error, unexpected EQ, expecting '(' "

Comment: Can you share the version of QGIS you are using and on which platform?

Also, I'd like to suggest instead of using field calculator to add a column for area you can skip that step and use the expression `$area=maximum($area)` directly in your expression.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54483/discussion-between-moo-and-nash).