# Removing unknown shape from polygon shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, geometry, overlapping-features, multipart

I have a shapefile of the region of districts. When I zoomed in, I found a region under the district that shouldn't be here. I want to remove it and when I go down in toggle editing, delete part it removes the whole district.

Is it possible to remove only two small regions (shown in the figure) from the whole district? When I try to find its identified features they have nothing in it, just overlay shape that I want to remove. Is there any way to get get rid of these 2 shapes? I am doing this analysis in QGIS.

[image]

Update 1st:

[image]

Comment: It's hard to tell what is going on here.  Those two shapes could be part of a multi-part polygon (in which case you would explode the multi-part polygon to single shapes and delete the unwanted portions), they could be holes in the polygon in which they are bound with another shape underneath with the same color( in which case you could delete the vertices that make the hole).  Can you re-post your image with the polygons symbolized with unique colors?

Comment: I have updated the image. I don't understand what you say unfortunately -GBG.

Comment: The shapes you want to remove seem to be parts of the large green feature and not self-standing features. In the same way than Alaska is part of USA. What is written above about exploding multipolygons is the way to go (if you want that Alaska disappears). And when you delete them you will have holes in the blue polygon.

Comment: Are you sure that it's not legitimate enclave from the green district in the blue district ? did you check how other map (google map, bing, osm, ...) display these area ?

Comment: Yes when I remove it. They create a hole in blue region. Is it any way to overcome this problem. because when I plot this on R it give me lines which create problem for my analysis -user30184.

Comment: I just checked the google map but they have nothing here -J.R

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Start editing
2. Select the part
3. Delete part
4. Draw a polygon on top of the hole
5. Select and merge

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Let's assume there is a polygon layer *'ne_10m_admin_0_countries_lakes'* with features that have some "problematic" geometries (data was taken from https://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_admin_0_countries_lakes.zip), see image below.

[image: input]

**Step 1.** Use the ["Geometry by expression"](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) geoalgorithm with the following expression:

```
geometry_n(
    order_parts(
        $geometry,
        'area($geometry)', 
        False
        )
    ,1
    )
```

Credits to [@Babel's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/383654/99589)

[image: step_1]

**Step 2.** Apply the ["Delete holes"](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#delete-holes) geoalgorithm

[image: step_2]

---

**References:**

- [Taking only the largest polygon from multi-polygon layer in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/383592/taking-only-the-largest-polygon-from-multi-polygon-layer-in-qgis)