# Converting clustered hexagonal grid units into polygons

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-2.18

I created a hexagonal grid using MMQGIS for my project and after some selection, I ended up with several clusters of units (as can be seen in the picture). I define as a cluster all the small hexagonal units that are connected.

What I wanted now is to convert these clusters into polygons so I can calculate the area of each polygon after. How can I do so?

QGIS version: 2.18.17
[image: Workspace]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Dissolve (Vector - Geoproccessing - Dissolve)
2. Multipart to Singlepart (Vector - Geometry Tools (?) - Multipart to Singlepart)
3. Calculate an area column, see: [Calculating polygon areas in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23355/calculating-polygon-areas-in-qgis)

[image]

Comment: This is precisely what I wanted! Thank you for your detailed answer!