# Calculating Ha of specific fields in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, qgis-3

[image: List of fields]

I use QGIS Bonn 3.2.0
So my question is how can i calculate Ha for specific fields i marked on picture.
Is there any tool and if yes which and how to use it?

Comment: where do you want those values? if in a new column, check [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23355/calculating-polygon-areas-in-qgis) (old, but still valid; also this is then a duplicate). you can use the field calculator also on selected fields only. for a quick glance, use the `Info tool` on a feature; you can find the spherical polygonal area under `derived`, in meters squared (mental math keeps you young).

Comment: I asked becoue latest answered was on version 2.2 or smth and this is 3.2, so I hope  this will not go into duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

If you mean Hectare the function you are looking for is `$area`

`$area` returns the area as map units so in a projected coordinate system it would be meter. Thus you need to divide the result by 10,000.

Create a new field with type numeric/float and use the field calculator with the formula `$area/10000`

Comment: I have few more question: do I need to choose every layer each time or is there way to just like copy paste from one to another?

Comment: @Roby5 You will need to create a new field and run this calculate for each layer.

Comment: And is there like switch so i can quick circle like in (google earth) between m*2 and Hektars?

Answer (score 3):

Use `$area/10000` in the field calculator. Provided, your data is in any UTM CRS and available as a shape-file.