# Calculated area is too large using Field Calculator in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, field-calculator, area

When I run the Field Calculator to update area, the resulting areas are too large. This happens whether I use QGIS 2.18 or QGIS 3.4.

The default CRS is set to: *ESPG:27700, OSGB 1936 / British National Grid*. However, somehow, the CRS has changed to *ESPG:4325, WGS 84*. When I change it back, the polygons do not appear on screen. If I recalculate `$area`, the amounts are `0.0000`.

Area default set as hectare, layer is a vector layer and all polygons are single part.

Example: using measuring tool gives area of one polygon at `7.441`, but the Field Calculator `$area = 12.1819`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please precise witch software you are using and if it's the CRS of the layer, of the project or both ?

Comment: I've just updated my post re: projection. I am usuing QGIS 2.18 (but have the same result with the most recent stable version, 3.4)

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "default CRS is set to". Do you mean the project's CRS? Or did you set the layer CRS? What CRS is the shapefile in? Where does it disappear to? Have you enabled `on the fly` reprojection?

Comment: Have a look at this link: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23355/calculating-polygon-areas-in-qgis

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 9):

There are many ways to get the area of a geometry. I leave here a summary.

---

The `$area` expression returns the ellipsoidal area (if there is a defined ellipsoid) in the units defined in the *Project Properties*, in the *Measurements* section of the *General* tab.

[image: 1]

---

The *Measure Area* tool, takes the coordinates from the canvas, but if an ellipsoid is selected in the *Project Properties*, *General*, *Measurement* section, it converts the coordinates to that ellipsoid and calculates the ellipsoidal areas. You can change the units for the tool.

[image: 2]

---

The `area($geometry)` expression, returns the planimetric area, calculated through the coordinates of the geometries in their layer CRS, with the units of their layer CRS.

---

With the *Identify* tool, you can get both, ellipsoidal (based on project ellipsoid) and planimetric (based on layer CRS) areas for a feature geometry.

[image: 3]

---

You can set *None / Planimetric* in the *Ellipsoid* field of the *Project Properties*, *General* tab, *Measurement* section.
In that case, the `$area` function and the *Measurement Area* tool will return the planimetric area calculated from the canvas coordinates. The *Identify* tool will no return an ellipsoidal area.

Canvas coordinates are based on the Project CRS (*Project Properties*, *CRS* tab). If the project don't have a CRS defined, you will see in the canvas rendered the layers in their original coordinates (without on the fly reprojection).

In *Settings* menu, *Options*, *CRS* tab you can define a defaul CRS for new projects, but you can change the project (canvas) CRS when you want trough the *Project Properties*, *CRS* tab.
Also, you can define a default CRS to assign to new layers when they have not a valid CRS already defined (I recommend you the *Prompt CRS* option, to find out when a layer without CRS is loaded).

The coordinates of a feature geometry in a layer, are defined in the layer CRS. Changing the layer CRS don't change the geometries coordinates. Reprojecting (or Exporting to a different CRS of) the layer change them.

Comment: Thanks very much, Gabriel. The first suggestion worked, with the correct measurements (although it doesn't work with hectares, only square metres). But now the layer is not visible on screen. When I 'pan to selection', the layer does appear, but none of the other layers (background maps) show. The same thing happens when I change from WGS84 to OSGB 1936 (the latter is the one I want to use, and the one I thought I'd selected!) I've got the data I need, but I would like to get this all to work for future projects.

Comment: @DS7 You are welcome. You can set _Hectares_ in the _Units for area measurement_ configuration of the Project Properties. Also you can use the `$area/10000` expression to convert square meters to hectares only in that field.

Comment: Setting hectares takes me back to the wrong calculations, but I have previously used the $area/10000 expression, so no problem there. Any idea why the layers disappear from the screen?

Comment: Re my last question. I've opened the project in QGIS 3.4 and it seems to be working fine, allowing me to set both project and layer projections as the same CRS. Point taken about being more specific.