# How to calculate the polyline area in QGIS

Tags: area, polyline-creation, rivers, shape-area

How to calculate the polyline area in QGIS?I have the width and length and I want to calculate the area of the river using that information so I can redraw my river using the area size calculated. However, idk ways to calculate the area using that information in QGIS.
[image: attribute table]
[image: my project]

Comment: I'd buffer https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/vector_spatial_analysis_buffers.html by the width then calculate the area of that polygon https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23355/calculating-polygon-areas-in-shapefile-using-qgis, not perfect but probably close enough.

Comment: oh means the buffer can represent the size of the poly line?

Comment: Yes, the buffer will be the area provided you buffer by half the width or you will exagerate the area and your data is in a suitable projected coordinate system.